# How to change the date format in the date field as a select list?

Tags: 8, datetime

On user registration page, I have added a date field in select list.

In the manage form display tab, I can set the order of the dropdown fields like day/month/year or month/day/year But I am unable to change the format of the date.

Currently in the day dropdown, it is displaying like `1, 2, 3` and I want to change it to `01, 02, 03`. Similarly in the month dropdown, it is displaying like, `Jan, Feb` and I want to display it like `January, February`.

Is this possible?

Comment: There's no way to do this through configuration, it will require programming. Are you comfortable with PHP?

Comment: yes. Any hook to alter?

Comment: Yes, you can use `hook_form_alter()`, locate the selector for the date, and amend the labels programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alter the way this component is shown globally, you can implement hook_preprocess_datetime_form(), eg. like this:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_datetime_form(&$variables) {
  // Ensure there's a month field and it's a select.
  if (isset($variables["content"]["month"]) && $variables["content"]["month"]['#type'] === 'select') {
    foreach ($variables["content"]["month"]['#options'] as $monthNum => $label) {
      if ($monthNum) {
        // Convert month number to unabbreviated name.
        $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
        $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');
        $variables["content"]["month"]['#options'][$monthNum] = $monthName;
  }
}
```

}

The code for the day select will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function <your_module>_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // your custom code here
}
```

You'll need to set the `#date_format` for your custom date field in the form array.

This entry in the [Drupal.org community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1364748) might help you with that.

The [PHP documentation for date formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) may also be helpful here.

Comment: The #date_format property is not working in Drupal 8.